# I’m an Australian resident with a UK residence permit. Can I stay in the Schengen area for more than 90 days?

Tags: schengen, freedom-of-movement, uk-residents

Does a tier 5 youth mobility visa (UK residence permit) grant me the same rights of Schengen movement as a UK citizen?

And if not, does anyone actually check? I got my passport stamped when I entered through the tunnel but they didn't seem to do any counting at the time…

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Has anyone who are non-EU travelled to Greece with UK work permit visa?](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/33787/has-anyone-who-are-non-eu-travelled-to-greece-with-uk-work-permit-visa) while that question is not 100% the same it does answer your question: a UK residence permit has no legal bearing on your Schengen rights.

Comment: voting against the duplicate - the questions are clearly related, but not the same. The marked duplicate asks if a UK residence permit waives the requirement for a visa to enter Schengen. This appears to be asking if the UK residence permit grants the holder Freedom of Movement rights. (Which it doesn't, by the way). The question *suggests* that the OP is normally a non-visa national for the Schengen area.

Comment: Kind of, but not because of your residence permit: https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/69255/which-schengen-countries-have-bilateral-agreements-which-ignore-the-standard-90

Answer (score 8):

I assume that you're actually a citizen of Australia, not just a resident, since that seems to be the interpretation under which the rest of the question makes the most sense. If that assumption is incorrect, please leave a comment on this answer, and I will change it as appropriate.

The UK residence permit has no bearing on your ability to spend time in the Schengen area.  (Indeed, holders of residence permits for *Schengen* countries are technically limited by the 90/180 rule when it comes to spending time in other Schengen countries.)

Does anyone actually check?  Sometimes they do.  They maybe more likely to check when you *leave* than when you enter, since that will be their first opportunity to catch you if you overstay.

I suppose they don't count all of everyone's Schengen stamps every time they cross the border because that would be too labor intensive, but neither do they have a policy of routinely ignoring the issue.  The potential negative consequences are severe, so you should think very carefully about whether you're willing to risk it.

If you want to spend more than 90 days in the Schengen area, you should either plan to spread them out sufficiently or look very seriously at whether you can get a working holiday visa or other long-stay visa for your desired destination.  This will give you 90 days out of 180 in the rest of the area.

Comment: Sorry but what is a whv?

Comment: @JosephP. "Working holiday visa" (one example of which is the UK's tier 4 youth mobility visa, which Aaron had).  I've edited the answer.